# ChartJS TypeError: document.getElementById(...).getContext is not a function

Tags: javascript, twig, chart.js

I am working with Symfony 2 and Twig Template. In Twig I want to draw **two** charts with Chart.js.

So I included the following `js`:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

To differentiate these charts, I am passing one changing Variable in a loop throw a function:

`{{ groupedDimension[0][0].dimension }}` equals `gaoperatingSystem` (in first loop) and `gascreenResolution` (in second loop)

```
{% for groupedDimension in groupedResults %}
    <script>
        var jQueryId = jQuery('#{{ groupedDimension[0][0].dimension }}').attr('id');
        drawChart(jQueryId);
    </script>
{% endfor %}
```

The function which creates the chart:

```
<script>
function drawChart(id) {
    var lineChartData = {
        labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
        datasets : [
            {
                label: "My First dataset",
                fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
            }
        ]
    }

    console.log(id);  //proves gaoperatingSystem and gascreenResolution
    window.onload = function(){
        var ctx = document.getElementById(id).getContext("2d");
        window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
            responsive: true
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

The Error shows at the line `var ctx = document.getElementById(id).getContext("2d");`

In the `html` I have the `divs` for the two charts:

```
{% for groupedDimension in groupedResults %}
    <div style="width:80%">
        <div>
            <canvas id="{{ groupedDimension[0][0].dimension }}" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
        </div>
     </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The browser console shows the following error message:

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...).getContext is not a function

What is causing the error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try surrounding your canvas id in ' -s, inside the existing doublequotes.

Comment: So I deleted some code rows, which González told me to.
Now it looks like: 

`var ctx = $(id).get(0).getContext("2d");
            new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData);`
Now it works just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part:

```
window.onload = ...
```

... replaces all previous `onload` event handlers attached to `window`. Since you are already using jQuery there's no need to this stuff manually, just:

```
jQuery(function($){
   // Do stuff
});
```

... as usual.